# TemplateProcessingException: Nested variables, map and foreach loop

Tags: java-8, thymeleaf, spark-java

I have the following models,

```
public class Shift {
    private UUID id;
    private UUID unit;
    private List employees;
    private Timestamp startTime;
    private Timestamp endTime;

    ...
}

public class Unit {
    private UUID id;
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

following route,

```
path("/shift", () -> {
    get("", ShiftController.fetchShifts);
});
```

following controller,

```
public static Route fetchShifts = (Request req, Response res) -> {
    Map map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("shifts", shiftDao.findAllByOrderByUnitAscStartTimeAsc());
    map.put("units", unitDao.findAllByOrderByName().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Unit::getId, u -> u)));
    return render(req, map, "shifts");
};
```

following template,

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="s : ${shifts}">
            <td th:text="*{units[__${s.unit}__].name}">unit</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

which gives me,

```
ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][qtp1905797065-18] Exception processing template "shifts": Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "units[dd002ece-10c7-11e7-9009-93b58da4760f].name"
...
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "units[dd002ece-10c7-11e7-9009-93b58da4760f].name"
...
Caused by: ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression: units[dd002ece-10c7-11e7-9009-93b58da4760f].name [ognl.ParseException: Encountered "  "c7 ""
...
```

and for the death of me I can't figure out the problem. What I want is to iterate through all the shifts and find out the name of the unit for each shift. For this I create a map `units` in the controller with the ids of units and objects representing them. However, I'm unsuccessful in implementing the map in the template. `*{units.get(__${s.unit}__).name}` in the template gives similar errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="s: ${shifts}">
            <td th:text="${units.get(s.unit).name}" />
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You have a few problems with your thymeleaf.

As the error message states, `units[dd002ece-10c7-11e7-9009-93b58da4760f].name` is not a valid expression.   As far as I know, you can only use the ${map[index]} expression with numbers (which look like map[0]) and strings (which look like map['test']).  Your expression is neither -- to the parser, you have a string missing the containing quotes.

Second, you're misusing `__${}__` expressions.  You should really only need to ever use `__${}__` when you are defining a `th:field` expression.  In most other cases, you should be able to do everything without them.